# Atomic Integer lazySet performance gains

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, atomic

The article "[Atomic*.lazySet is a performance win for single writers](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/atomiclazyset-is-performance-win-for.html)," goes over how `lazySet` is a weak volatile write (in the sense that it acts as a store-store and not a store-load fence). But I don't understand how leveraging semi-volatile writes improves concurrent queue performance. How exactly does it offer extra low latency as [claimed by Menta-queue](http://mentaqueue.soliveirajr.com/Page.mtw)?

I already read up on it's implementation and it's claims on the stack overflow question: "[How is lazySet in Java's Atomic* classes implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381440/how-is-lazyset-in-javas-atomic-classes-implemented)" and "[Atomic Integer's lazySet vs set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381440/how-is-lazyset-in-javas-atomic-classes-implemented)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a volatile write on x86 is that it issues full memory barrier which results in a stall until the [store buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105827/what-is-a-store-buffer) is drained. Meanwhile `lazySet` on x86 is a simple store. It does not require all previous stores waiting in the store buffer to be flushed, thus allowing writing thread to proceed at full speed.

This is described a bit in [Martin Thompson's article](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ru/2013/02/cpu-cache-flushing-fallacy.html).

Comment: hey apangin, thank you for the article and the explanation! I had to dig way back into my computer architecture knowledge to connect all the dots here, but your explanation and Martin Thompson's article was great. hope you have a good week ahead!